# миграция с модели в yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

ребят можно ли создать миграцию основываясь на models? если можно подскажите как?

Comment: Можно, но не нужно т. к. модель в дальнейшем может изменится, а миграцию подстраивать под модель не очень хорошо. Был в практике такой печальный опыт.

Comment: просто у меня есть проект без базы данных, предыдущий человек не сделал миграцию, и я хотел бы снова базу собрать, не пойму как сделать?

Comment: Евгений, если Вы создаёте миграцию, то модель генерируется на основе таблицы, которая создана миграцией. Если меняете модель, то надо создавать соответствующую миграцию. Это нормально.

Comment: Worker Testovich, совсем нет базы? Дамп базы никак получить нельзя?

Comment: никак из-за этого я и пытаюсь чтото с этим сделать

Comment: то есть, базы вообще никакой нет, только модели с атрибутами?

Comment: да именно так, без какой либо базы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить такой вариант. 
Не очень удобно, но, думаю, будет быстрей, чем писать какие-то классы.
Открываете первую модель. Находите метод attributeLabels(), выделяете и копируете.
Создаёте миграцию, называете её по имени модели. Например так

```
 php yii migrate/create model_name_table
```

Вставляете в метод saveUp() скопированный кусок кода из модели и немного изменяете.

Было

```
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
      return [
        'id' => 'Id Car Serie',
        'name' => 'Name',
        'date_create' => 'Date Create',
        'date_update' => 'Date Update',
      ];
    }
```

Стало

```
    public function saveUp()
    {
       $this->createTable('{{%table_name}}',[
        'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
        'name' => $this->string(),
        'date_create' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
        'date_update' => $this->integer()->notNull(),,
      ]);
    }

    public function saveDown()
    {
       $this->dropTable('{{%table_name}}');
    }
```

И так со всеми моделями. Только надо будет учесть индексы, внешние ключи и связи.

После того, как сделаете миграции в консоли применяете их

```
php yii migrate --interactive=0
```

Вот как-то так...